# Some Finder icons previewing as text when they shouldn't

Tags: finder, preview, icon, quicklook

I have this problem in my main user account which manifest itself that some file types in the Finder incorrectly preview as text. For example I have several .dmg file that looks like this:

[image: DMG file getting previewed as text in the Finder]

They also preview as text if i use Quick Look on them.

I have tried resetting all in `~/Library/Preferences` (I moved all items in there to a different folder temporarily and logged out and back in again). I have cleared everything in `~/Library/Caches` and I have nothing  in `~/Library/QuickLook`

I have also tried doing a Safe Boot and then restarting normally.

Any ideas of what to try next?

Okay, I've now found that the problem goes away if I log into the Guest Account, but it is still there if I create a new ”Standard” user. Hmm…

Comment: You said that you have checked `~/Library/QuickLook`, but did you also check `/Library/QuickLook` (i.e., the QuickLook folder in your root Library folder)? If the behavior is indeed caused by a QuickLook plug-in in `/Library/QuickLook`, that would explain why you also see it for a newly created user account.

Comment: I looked there and I have: **iBooksAuthor.qlgenerator** and **iWork.qlgenerator** there.

Tried removing those and restarting the computer – no difference. So thanks, but the problem is somewhere else it seems.

Comment: I have no idea what fixed it, but just today I noticed the problem is gone for me in my main account. I'm totally clueless.
Hmm… Maybe it's related to the Xcode 9.4.1 update I Installed yesterday? ”Fixes a security issue  in the included Git support and command-line tool”.